# Can i create a Github feature branch from Azure Boards?

Tags: azure-devops

I am testing out how Azure Boards and Github work. I connected my repo from our organisation and connected Github and seems fine but in the Azure DevOps project i have the default Git repo and when i try to create a branch for a issue i can only choose the default Azure DevOps repo and no Github repo.

/donnib

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the Azure Boards app for GitHub doesn't support branch. By installing the Azure Boards app for GitHub, you can configure and manage the connections of your Azure Boards projects (hosted service only) with your GitHub.com repositories. By connecting your Azure Boards projects with GitHub.com repositories, you support linking between GitHub commits and pull requests to work items. You can use GitHub for software development while using Azure Boards to plan and track your work.

[image]

Comment: Thx, that's such a shame. It's a crucial feature for us to make it easy to create branches from the Work item name. Something we are really happy to have in the Atlassian stack we use today.

Comment: Feel free to submit a suggestion at website below: https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/report?entry=suggestion&space=21.

Comment: Is my reply helpful?